# calling viewpager page2 from page 1 in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

1. First i have one activity in which i have view pager
2. Each page of view pager holds fragment
3. Now in first page fragment i have button and when i click on button i want page two of view pager,
   **when i click view all it should open womens page which is position2 of viewpager **

   [image: here is my main activity viewpager page 1 when i click view all it should go to next page]

[image: here i should go]

Comment: I need to solve this asap. So plz share your views and solution plz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a method in the Activity (containing the ViewPager and the sub-fragments) like so:

```
public void setPagerFragment(int a)
{
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(a);
}
```

This will set the current Fragment in the ViewPager to be the one specified. You can then call this method from any child Fragment with:

```
int newFrag = 0; //the number of the new Fragment to show
ParentActivity parent = (ParentActivity) getActivity();
parent.setPagerFragment(newFrag);
```